# What does it mean for a function to converge at a point of discontinuity?

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-series

In Fourier analysis, if $x$ is a point of discontinuity of $f(x)$, then $f(x)=\frac{f(x^+)+f(x^-)}{2}$. How is this Convergence? Uniform convergence? Pointwise convergence?

Comment: Pointwise convergence.

Comment: Fourier series are series of continuous functions. Uniform convergence would imply that the limit is continuous, which in general is incompatible with the series converging to $f$ (and to the average values at discontinuities).

Comment: The function still has the value $f(x)$. Is the sum of the Fourier series that has the value $(f(x^+)+f(x^-))/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Fourier Series terms are continuous functions (sines and cosines), so in case of uniform convergence the sum of the series should be a continuous function.

If it is not, then the convergence cannot be uniform.